# No puedo acceder al WP! Call to undefined function create_function() ..... wp-includes/pomo/translations.php

Tags: php, wordpress

No puedo acceder al WordPress, y me salta el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function create_function() in /homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php:208 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php(269): Gettext_Translations->make_plural_form_function(2, '$n != 1') #1 /homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php(69): Gettext_Translations->set_header('Plural-Forms', 'nplurals=2; plu...') #2 /homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php(248): Translations->set_headers(Array) #3 /homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-includes/pomo/mo.php(27): MO->import_from_reader(Object(POMO_FileReader)) #4 /homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-includes/l10n.php(484): MO->import_from_file('/homepages/17/d...') #5 /homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-includes/load.php(827): load_textdomain('default', '/homepages/17/d...') #6 /homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-includes/wp-db.php(1489): wp_load_translations_early() #7 /homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-includes/wp-db.php(649): wpdb->db_connect() #8 /homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-includes/load.php(350): wpdb->__construct('db133936_D76_2', 'ellyseoyuhn!s4', 'db133936_jasimb...', 'internal-db.s13...') #9 /homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-settings.php(79): require_wp_db() #10 /homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-config.php(90): require_once('/homepages/17/d...') #11 /homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/homepages/17/d...') #12 /homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-login.php(12): require('/homepages/17/d...') #13 {main} thrown in /homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php on line 208

Comment: Explica qué haces para que aparezca ese error y dinos si tu WP funciona, si puedes navegar por los posts etc.

Comment: Que versión de wordpress estas utilizando? La función create_function() esta en desuso, actualiza tu wordpress o baja tu versión de php, también explica los pasos que hiciste para que apareciese el error y verifica que el error no este en un plugin o en el core de wordpress.

Comment: ese error puede saltar cuando uno o varios plugins no son compatibles con php 8 https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php

Answer (score 0):

lo que veo es que en el archivo translations.php en la línea 208 estás llamando la función create_function() y esta al parecer está indefinida.
/homepages/17/d911774543/htdocs/viejoven17a22/wp-includes/pomo/translations.php:208

Te recomiendo que revises ese archivo y prestes atención al hoisting de la función.
Posiblemente sea que no tienes la función creada, o que la función esté creada pero la estés llamando antes de la creación.
Como dijo el del primer comentario, ¿que tratas de hacer para que salga ese error?

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).